# Two questions re. Biblatex: How do I move the URL to the very end of the reference, and how do I remove the . after the title of a collection?

Tags: biblatex

I'm currently using a modified version of BibLaTeX, with the [`ext-authoryear-comp` style](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/master/ext-authoryear-comp.bbx). I have managed to get it to look like this by cobbling together bits of code from here and there (I use LyX, so I'm not too familiar with using the LaTeX language):

[image: References]

But I need to remove the `.` after the title of collections and edited books and the `by` after `ed.`, to make it look like so:

[image]

Furthermore, I need the URL of the last reference to be the very last item listed, and I need to replace `visited on` with `accessed on`. Any ideas, anyone?

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.2.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,british]{paper}
\usepackage{libertine-type1}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=false]

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear-comp,giveninits=true, urldate=long]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes,xpatch} % Xpatch is needed to move (ed.) around.
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{microtype}
\addbibresource{Complete.bib}
% Bibliography Settings for JMS
% Remove p., pp., &c.
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
% Delimit year with period and no brackets.
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addperiod\space}
% Remove In from articles.
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\addspace\nopunct}}
}
% Do not print month and day fields.
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{day}}
%Do not italicize inbook, article, inproceedings fields.
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook, article, inproceedings]{title}{#1} 
% Ampersand instead of and.
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space} 
% Volume and number bold; number in brackets.
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}
}
% Ed. lowercase.
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}{\printtext}{\printtext[parens]}{}{}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \addcomma\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{book}{\newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}{%
\setunit{\addspace}\newblock%
\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
}{}{}

% Colon for article pages.
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addperiod\addspace}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{\mkbibbold#1}}
%Change URL 
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}
% End bibliography settings for JMS
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0308}{}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{UKenglish}{%
  \uspunctuation%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Methods and Best Practices}
\maketitle

  Blah blah

\parencite[50]{aristotle_nicomachean_1995}

\parencite[50]{arrighi_tracking_2003}

\parencite[50]{badiou_subject_2006}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

`Complete.bib` is provided below:

```
@inbook{aristotle_nicomachean_1995,
  langid = {english},
  location = {{Princeton, NJ}},
  title = {Nicomachean {{Ethics}}},
  volume = {2},
  isbn = {978-0-691-01650-4},
  shorttitle = {The Complete Works of {{Aristotle}}},
  volumes = {2},
  number = {72},
  booktitle = {The Complete Works of {{Aristotle}}: The Revised {{Oxford}} Translation},
  series = {Bollingen Series},
  publisher = {{Princeton University Press}},
  date = {1995},
  pages = {2487},
  author = {Aristotle},
  bookauthor = {Aristotle},
  editor = {Barnes, Jonathan},
  translator = {Ross, W.D. and Urmson, J.O.}
}

@article{badiou_subject_2006,
  title = {The {{Subject}} Supposed to Be a {{Christian}}: {{On Paul Ric{\oe}ur}}'s '{{Memory}}, {{History}}, {{Forgetting}}'},
  volume = {2},
  url = {http://novaojs.newcastle.edu.au/ojsbct/index.php/bct/article/viewFile/96/82},
  number = {3},
  journaltitle = {The Bible and Critical Theory},
  urldate = {2016-07-26},
  date = {2006},
  pages = {27.1-27.9},
  author = {Badiou, Alain},
  translator = {Doyle, Natalie and Toscano, Alberto},
}

@article{arrighi_tracking_2003,
  title = {Tracking Global Turbulence},
  volume = {20},
  journaltitle = {New Left Review},
  date = {2003},
  pages = {5},
  author = {Arrighi, Giovanni},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please consider making you code example a fully self-contained [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). Ideally one could just copy, paste and run the code from your question. For now we don't have your `.bib` entries and the document body is missing. Your question is probably answerable without a full MWE, but it makes answering much easier. It makes sure that we are all talking about the same thing. And it shows that you value our time by not letting us reproduce what you have.

Comment: Also, please consider asking only one thing per question. That makes it easier to answer your question for people who only know solutions to some of your questions. It also helps future visitors find the information they need more easily. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864

Comment: @moewe I've made the question into an MWE and included a bibliography link; hopefully I've done this properly. Apologies for posting two questions in one, I didn't think it would be a problem but your observation is valid..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try the code below. I modernised some small details in your code (use options to remove the "in" for `@articles` and month and day from dates, use the `biblatex-ext`-specific `\volnumdelim` to avoid redefining an entire macro).

The "ed. by" could be changed to "ed." by using `editor+othersstrg` instead of `byeditor+othersstrg`.

`\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{urlseen={accessed on},}` should be enough for the URL thing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear-comp, giveninits=true, uniquename=init, date=year, urldate=long, articlein=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{aristotle_nicomachean_1995,
  langid = {english},
  location = {{Princeton, NJ}},
  title = {Nicomachean {{Ethics}}},
  volume = {2},
  isbn = {978-0-691-01650-4},
  shorttitle = {The Complete Works of {{Aristotle}}},
  volumes = {2},
  number = {72},
  booktitle = {The Complete Works of {{Aristotle}}: The Revised {{Oxford}} Translation},
  series = {Bollingen Series},
  publisher = {{Princeton University Press}},
  date = {1995},
  pages = {2487},
  author = {Aristotle},
  bookauthor = {Aristotle},
  editor = {Barnes, Jonathan},
  translator = {Ross, W.D. and Urmson, J.O.}
}

@article{badiou_subject_2006,
  title = {The {{Subject}} Supposed to Be a {{Christian}}: {{On Paul Ric{\oe}ur}}'s '{{Memory}}, {{History}}, {{Forgetting}}'},
  volume = {2},
  url = {http://novaojs.newcastle.edu.au/ojsbct/index.php/bct/article/viewFile/96/82},
  number = {3},
  journaltitle = {The Bible and Critical Theory},
  urldate = {2016-07-26},
  date = {2006},
  pages = {27.1-27.9},
  author = {Badiou, Alain},
  translator = {Doyle, Natalie and Toscano, Alberto},
}

@article{arrighi_tracking_2003,
  title = {Tracking Global Turbulence},
  volume = {20},
  journaltitle = {New Left Review},
  date = {2003},
  pages = {5},
  author = {Arrighi, Giovanni},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Bibliography Settings for JMS
% Remove p., pp., &c.
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
% Delimit year with period and no brackets.
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addperiod\space}

%Do not italicize inbook, article, inproceedings fields.
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook, article, inproceedings]{title}{#1} 
% Ampersand instead of and.
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space} 
% Volume and number bold; number in brackets.
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
% Ed. lowercase.
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \addcomma\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{book}{\newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}{%
\setunit{\addspace}\newblock%
\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
}{}{}

% Colon for article pages.
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addperiod\addspace}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{\mkbibbold{#1}}}
%Change URL 
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{urlseen={accessed on},}
% End bibliography settings for JMS
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0308}{}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{UKenglish}{%
  \uspunctuation%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\parencite[50]{aristotle_nicomachean_1995}

\parencite[50]{arrighi_tracking_2003}

\parencite[50]{badiou_subject_2006}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much! The only issue that remains is how to switch the order of the URL and the date of access, i.e. to have Accessed on 26th July 2016. URL:<url>, but it's a relatively minor one.

Comment: @LukeScicluna Have a look at the `url+urldate` macro in `biblatex.def`. You can ask a new question if you need help. That is one of the reasons why I asked you to only ask one question per question. It is easy to forget a requirement if there are many. Although I must admit it was not that I forgot this part of the question, I simply did not understand that you wanted the URL and URLdate switched when you wrote that you wanted the URL to be the last item.